# ShareThis Button to Open in Popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, sharethis

I am using Sharethis button for social media sharing. The problem is that when you click on Twitter, Facebook, Linkedin or any other button, it open in new tab. I want it to open in popup window. Is that possible to do. Here is the code I am using.

This goes in head section

```
    <script type="text/javascript">var switchTo5x=true;</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">stLight.options({publisher: "ur-3a946ea7-4e9c-2bf6-f820-37c233b1bc9c", doNotHash: false, doNotCopy: false, hashAddressBar: false});</script>
```

And this goes in the body of the page.

```
<span class='st_sharethis_large' displayText='ShareThis'></span>
<span class='st_facebook_large' displayText='Facebook'></span>
<span class='st_twitter_large' displayText='Tweet'></span>
<span class='st_linkedin_large' displayText='LinkedIn'></span>
<span class='st_pinterest_large' displayText='Pinterest'></span>
<span class='st_email_large' displayText='Email'></span>
```

This did not work either.

```
<script type="text/javascript">var switchTo5x=true;</ script>
<script type="text/javascript" src=" w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js"></ script> 
<script type="text/ javascript">
  stLight.options({
    publisher: "ur-3a946ea7-4e9c-2bf6- f820-37c233b1bc9c", 
    popup: 'true' 
    doNotHash: false, 
    doNotCopy: false, 
    hashAddressBar: false
 });
 </script>
```

Comment: RTM: http://support.sharethis.com/customer/portal/articles/475019-open-widget-in-new-window-

Comment: I tried this code which didn't work. please tell what I did wrong.  <script
type="text/javascript">var switchTo5x=true;</
script> <script type="text/javascript"
src=" w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js"></
script> ; <script type="text/
javascript">stLight.options({publisher:
"ur-3a946ea7-4e9c-2bf6-
f820-37c233b1bc9c", popup: 'true'
doNotHash: false, doNotCopy: false,
hashAddressBar: false});</script>

Comment: You for sure forgot a comma after `true,`<<<< and you have a space after `text/` and after `</`before `script>`

Comment: Plus it should be `popup: true`, not `popup: 'true'`

Answer (score 12):

Besides the `popup` option, you'll want to set the `servicePopup` option to `true` when calling `stLight.options()`.

Answer (score 4):

```
<script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript" src="http://w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js"></script>
<script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript">
    stLight.options({
        "publisher":"####",
        "doNotCopy":false,
        "hashAddressBar":false,
        "doNotHash":false,
        "servicePopup":true
    });
</script>
```

I got this script working with ShareThis plugin, with:

```
"servicePopup":true
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the button.js plugin that you are using..
If you had a link you could specify WHERE to open it, or with JS

```
window.open("www.youraddress.com","_self")
```

But since you're using a pre-made plugin you can't change that.

You could create your own script to open a specific page on class click with something like

```
$('.stack').click(function(){
    window.location = 'www.stackoverflow.com';
});
```

EDIT: Or as you can see from the comment on the question, that plugin supports option flags. My bad, haven't checked it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried that but it didn't work. I changed the head section code to this. Please see what i did wrong. '<script type="text/javascript">var switchTo5x=true;</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">stLight.options({publisher: "ur-3a946ea7-4e9c-2bf6-f820-37c233b1bc9c", popup: 'true' doNotHash: false, doNotCopy: false, hashAddressBar: false});</script>'